# Find if an array present in the mongo Database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Conversation Schema

```js
const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    recipients: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User' }],
    lastMessage: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
})
```

I want to know if there exist an array `[ patientId, doctorId ]`
Here is my main approach to find
I am not able to get the response and I already have one document with that same array

```js
const conversationBetween = await Conversation.findOne(
            {
                recipients: { 
                    $all: [
                        { $elemMatch: { $eq: patientId }},
                        { $elemMatch: { $eq: doctorId }}
                    ],
                }
            }
        )

        
        if (conversationBetween) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                status: "failed",
                message: "You already have a conversation with this doctor"
            });
        }
```

following Code to add a Conversation in the Conversation Collection, this works fine

```js
const newConversation = new Conversation({
            recipients: [ patientId,doctorId ],
            lastMessage: `I want to get consultation`,
            date: Date.now(),
        })

        await newConversation.save()

        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            message: "Conversation added successfully",
            conversation: newConversation
        });
```

The main purpose is to make sure that if there present an entry with `[ patientId, doctorId ]` in Conversation it should not make a new entry..
But at this time its not able to find and is making that same entry.

Comment: Try `$all: [ patientId,doctorId ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
await Conversation.findOne(
            {
                recipients: [patientId, doctorId]
  }
)
```

Working in [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQUVg1pNKYW)

Comment: Yess This worked.. but I have to change `findOne` to just `find` , don't know why